# PHP Getting files in a directory

Tags: php, mysql

First, this might be a stupid question for some but as I am a newbie to this, I am still learning while doing things. So here's my question :

I am trying to get all files in a directory so that I can insert its content to the database. I am currently using localhost. Using [glob()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function, I got what I need. But here's where I have a problem. Since [glob()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function returns an arraylist of filenames, how can I get the filename currently being read, and insert that also in the database table?

Here's my current code w/c I got from this [site](http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql) :

```
$dir = "MyFiles/";
$curFile = glob($dir."*.csv");


foreach ($curFile as $filename) {
   $handle = fopen($filename,"r");
   }
   //loop through the file
   do{
      if ($data[0]) {
         mysql_query (" INSERT INTO tblCoordinates (id,filename,lat,lon)
         VALUES
         ('',
          '.$filename.',
          '".addslashes($data[0])."',
          '".addslashes($data[1])."')
         ");

   } while ($data = fgetcsv ($handle,1000,",","'"));
}
```

Again, I also need the filenames to be inserted to the database, but with my current code, the filename is not inserted.

Comment: what is `if (data[0]) {` condition in your code????

Comment: where is come from???

Comment: added that information above @Saty, thanks

Comment: `print_r($filename)` what is the result if it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed: 
In your statement `'.$filename.'` is wrong. It should be `'$filename'` ...

You should assemble the sql command first and then execute it as a single statement like this:

```
$glob=glob($dir."*.csv");
foreach ($glob as $filename) {
  $handle = fopen($filename,"r");
  while ($da = fgetcsv ($handle,1000,",","'")) {
    if ($da[0]) $data[]="('','$filename','".JOIN("','",array_slice($da,0,2))."')";
  }
} 
$mysql="INSERT INTO tblCoordinates (id,filename,lat,lon)  VALUES\n".JOIN(",\n",$data);
// echo $mysql // --> check it first ...
mysql_query($mysql);
```

Running on my data in `$dir='./'` the `echo` gave me this

```
INSERT INTO tblCoordinates (id,filename,lat,lon)  VALUES 
('','./dat.csv','1','23'),
('','./dat.csv','2','27'),
('','./dat.csv','3','31'),
('','./dat.csv','4','35'),
('','./dat.csv','5','39')
```

What is your statement like and - most of all - your error message?

---

(And, of course: the `mysql_query()` function is deprecated, use `mysqli_query()` instead ...)

Comment: I really want to use mysqli, as that is what supposed to be used but my boss said I just use mysql. So, I can't argue with that. Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: Sir @cars10, again Thank you, I have tried this, but now, its not inserting into my table.

Comment: I usually try out the generated SQL commands in a separate SQL command window first before switch my php scripts to go 'live' ...

Comment: Just noticed the curious `''` values in the `VALUES` clause: If `id` is an `auto_increment` column then you should probably **leave this column out of your insert statement** altogether, like `INSERT INTO tblCoordinates (filename,lat,lon)  VALUES ('./dat.csv','1','23'), ...`

Comment: Thank you for all the tips and the help Sir Cars10

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you should use this approach.
You might (and probably will) kill your database every time you run the script (especially if you have many files in this directory and many line in each csv file).
It would seem better to prepare a transaction, one insert with many values, then commit.
That way, you will also be able to easily echo the query to see if everything is alright.

Note that you should check if filename is a file or a directory (I am not sure about . and .. but you might need to check that too)

Also, I would recommend doing something like

```
$someVar = glob($dir."*.csv");
foreach($someVar as $filename) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Yes, there's a chance that that there would be many files in the folder, and   many lines in the csv file, Though I know that the directory exists, I do not know the filenames that are in that directory. So, I used glob(). But I cannot get the filename. In the table, the value of filename is na-da

Comment: Have you tried using xdebug ? or maybe var_dump($filename); to check the different filenames.
I am pretty sure you have some special case here and since you do not use prepared statements, if filename has special characters, if could break your insert ro give strange results.

Comment: I ust realised that you edited your code, and you seem to have a trailing } right after the fopen; which breaks your loop!